# AngularJS : How would i return value from factory if the data is fetched with http

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I have this factory in angular:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('finansiiApp')
  .factory('transactions', function ($http) {
    var transactions = [];
    $http.get("/api/transactions.json")
      .success(function(data, status){
        transactions = data;
      });

    // Public API here
    return {
      getTransactions: function () {
        return transactions;
      },
      addTransaction: function(transaction){
        transactions.push(transaction);
      }
    };
  });
```

This is my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('finansiiApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, transactions) {
    $scope.searchText = "";
    $scope.filterPrimanja = $scope.filterTrosoci = true;
    console.log(transactions);
    $scope.transactions = transactions.getTransactions();
    $scope.clicked = function(index){
      console.log(index);
    }
  });
```

Now as you probably guessed, my data in the controller(where i call the getTransactions method) is not updated on success. How would i go about making this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you could change. (and ways you could change them). 1 being the most suggested/correct.

1. Use promises and callbacks in your controller so...

   ```
   // your controller... ($scope.transactions line)
   transactions.getTransactions().then(function(data){
       $scope.transactions = data;
   }

   // your service..
   angular...factory('transactions',function($http,$q){
       var transactions = [];
       return {
           getTransactions: function(){
              //is a request needed?
              if(transactions.length > 0){
                  var deferred = $q.defer();
                  deferred.resolve(transactions);
                  return deferred.promise;
              }
              return $http.get("/api/transactions.json").then(function(result){
                  //modify collection of transactions...
                  transactions = result.data;
                  return transactions; // this is data ^^ in the controller
              });
           }
           addTransaction: function(transaction){
               //do more http stuff?
               //wrap function in promise so its consistent and will also run digest.
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               transactions.push(transaction);
               deferred.resolve(transactions);
               return deferred.promise;
           }
       }

   });
   ```
2. Modify `var transactions = [];` instead of just wiping it out. eg. iterate over new data and push/pop unshift, concat w/e Objects bound in angular need to be idempotent

Another thing to keep in mind is that services are instantiated just once. While controllers are being created and destroyed all the time.. You might not have to make the request every time so perhaps before returning $http promise in `getTransactions` you could check to see if you need to make the request. Then manually use a promise.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.
One question though, why is this:
    sactions.getTransactions().then(function(data){
    $scope.transactions = data;

Comment: You need to perform the asynchronous operation (http get). The anonymous function in `then` has closure to your controller so it can modify `$scope` sometime in the future.

Comment: Yeah i tried it, but now it doesn't save new things from other controllers.

Comment: Oh, now like you said, I always make an ajax request when this controller is called. So basically i need to make it so it keeps some kind of cache and not to call it every time(since i'm still using a mock version of addTransaction, but also in production i wouldn't want to call it everytime if not needed.

Comment: `var transactions = [];` is your cache. I updated the `getTransactions` method in the answer